# Magento2: How to merge tab (description and additonal details)

Tags: magento2, tabs

I want to merge these 2 tabs because is an issue in mobile view (too wide):

https://prnt.sc/o2a0be

https://prnt.sc/o2a0dj

Anyone help how can I do it?

Comment: can you please provide in english language which tab you want to merge

Comment: @Prashant Valanda First tab is with description product and second tab is with product attribute. i want merge these 2 tabs to one

Comment: Here you have screen how I try to do: https://prnt.sc/o2gg8a

Comment: You can check in  our code: https://zabezcen.pl/pl/sneakersy-ja15286g07jx-33860.html